# Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2' is not defined or imported

Tags: c#

I have a .NET solution file with about 20 C# projects. All of them are targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2. Within a couple of projects, I can easily write `var t = ("hello", "world");` and the compiler is happy. But within some projects of the same solution, the compilation fails with `` Predefined type System.ValueTuple`2 is not defined or imported `` for the exact same piece of code.

I've already checked the following things:

- There is no `mscorlib.dll` anywhere in the solution or project directories.
- `bin` and `obj` have been deleted several times.
- Problem can be reproduced on a colleagues computer.
- Not a single project is using the NuGet package `System.ValueTuple`.
- I did a text search across all `*.csproj` files for `ValueTuple` without any match.

I know that there are dozens of articles related to this error. But most of them are just saying: install the NuGet package or update your .NET Framework version. Unfortunately, none of them seems to cover the problem I'm encountering. Rather than installing or upgrading anything, I'd like to understand the behavior.

Comment: in the ones where it works, it is *somehow* getting a reference (perhaps transitively?) to either the assembly in the GAC, or a nuget package; frankly, though, value-tuple on net46* is a massive PITA, and really isn't worth the pain it can cause; it is basically getting to the point where I'd say simply "don't use value-tuple unless you're targeting .net core"

Comment: Since not a single project is using the NuGet package, this is not an option. You suspect a transitive dependency to `System.ValueTuple.dll` in the GAC?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the culprit: there is one project targeting .NET Standard 2.0. Every .NET Framework project referencing the .NET Standard project automatically gets a reference to `System.ValueTuple.dll` from the GAC (in my case, this is .NET Framework 4.7.2).
Each project without referencing the .NET Standard project does not have the reference. Therefore, the snippet `var t = ("hello", "world");` cannot be used.